# Perl for SNMP V3 Not Working, but works with SNMP V1/2 (Redhat Linux)

Tags: linux, perl, snmp, net-snmp

I have a Perl Script, which registers SNMP OIDs. With SNMP 1/2c, it is able to successfully register all OIDs. However, with SNMP V3, it only partially works.

As you see below, with SNMP V3, it is able to register "$root_OID.0.0.0" successfully. However, it timeouts when trying to invoke the java code for "$root_OID.0.0.1".

Does anyone know, why I'm able to make a successful java call in SNMP V1/2c, but not SNMP V3?

Many Thanks

Here is my Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use NetSNMP::OID (':all'); 
use NetSNMP::ASN qw(ASN_OCTET_STR ASN_INTEGER);
use NetSNMP::agent (':all');

sub myhandler { 
    my ($handler, $registration_info, $request_info, $requests) = @_; 
    my $request;
    my $root_OID = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.9999.9999.0"; 

    my $CLASSPATH = "/opt/BPL/JBoss/BPL_JBossJMX.jar:/opt/jboss-5.1/client/*";
    my $CLASSNAME = "com.XXXXX.XXXXX.XXXXX.jmx.BPLJbossJMX_For_SNMP";
    my $ENV = "localhost";
    my $PORT = "8099";  
    my $LOG4JFILELOC = "/opt/BPL/JBoss/JBoss-BPL-Log4j.xml";

    for($request = $requests; $request; $request = $request->next()) { 
        my $oid = $request->getOID(); 
        if ($request_info->getMode() == MODE_GETNEXT) { 
            if ($oid < new NetSNMP::OID("$root_OID.0.0.0")) { 
                my $INPUTSTRNAME = "HeapMemoryUsageZZZZZ";
                $request->setOID("$root_OID.0.0.0"); 
                $request->setValue(ASN_OCTET_STR, $INPUTSTRNAME); 
            } elsif ($oid < new NetSNMP::OID("$root_OID.0.0.1")) {
                my $INPUTSTRNAME = "HeapMemoryUsage";
                my $OUTPUT= `java -cp $CLASSPATH $CLASSNAME $ENV $PORT $INPUTSTRNAME $LOG4JFILELOC`;
                chomp($OUTPUT);
                $request->setOID("$root_OID.0.0.1");
                $request->setValue(ASN_INTEGER, $OUTPUT);
            }
        } 
    }     
}

my $rootOID = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.9999.9999.0"; 
my $regoid = new NetSNMP::OID($rootOID); 
$agent->register("BPL-JBoss", $regoid, \&myhandler);
```

Here is my /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf file (SNMP V1/2c disabled):

```
###############################################################################
# snmpd.conf:
###############################################################################

#com2sec notConfigUser  default       public

#       groupName      securityModel securityName
#group   notConfigGroup v1            notConfigUser
#group   notConfigGroup v2c           notConfigUser

view   systemview    included   .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2
view   systemview    included   .1.3.6.1.2.1
view   systemview    included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.1
view   systemview    included   .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021       
view   systemview    included   .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.9999.9999

#access  notConfigGroup ""      any       noauth    exact  systemview none none

###############################################################################
syslocation Unknown (edit /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf)
syscontact Root <root@localhost> (configure /etc/snmp/snmp.local.conf)

###############################################################################
pass .1.3.6.1.4.1.4413.4.1 /usr/bin/ucd5820stat

###############################################################################
perl do "/home/XXXXXXX/JBoss_hello_world.pl"
rouser TEST_USERNAME priv
```

Here is the results of my SNMPWALK, when using SNMPV3.

```
-$snmpwalk -v 3 -l authPriv -a sha -A TEST_PASSWORD -x AES -X TEST_PASSWORD -u TEST_USERNAME localhost .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.9999.9999
NET-SNMP-MIB::netSnmpPlaypen.0.0.0.0 = STRING: "HeapMemoryUsageZZZZZ"
Timeout: No Response from localhost
```

Comment: Bump. Help. Anyone with answer?